# powerpoint vba texteffect adjustments handle

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I can't figure out how to manipulate the adjustment handle (the pink diamond pointed to by the arrow below) in powerpoint 2010 vba.  myshape.adjustments.count returns 0 and thus any attempts at setting myshape.Adjustments.Item(1) to a value returns an error. I created the text manually using a Text Box shape, added a bevel, then Text Effects, Transform, Circle. The handle lets you change the arc size and width of the text. Is this handle available through vba?

[image]

Comment: I've even gone so far as to try and do this in Excel, so that I could try and use the Macro Recorder. The macro recorder does not recognize this operation, either. I think you will not be able to do this in VBA, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the object model, the `TextEffect` doesn't have an Adjustment handle available through VBA. This seems odd, since that does appear to be an Adjustments handle. Perhaps it is a bug or oversight, in any case, that is kind of a problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193987.aspx

You might be able to play with these properties of a Shape object, to achieve the desired results:

`shp.TextEffect.Parent.Rotation`

`shp.TextEffect.Parent.Width`

`.Rotation` property takes a double type value between 0 and 180, 0 would be no rotation, 180 would be upside-down.

`.Width` property takes a double type value, I think any value would be allowable, just sets the width of the shape, so, make it larger or smaller depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks David, but the effect I'm looking for is when the handle is moved left or right it changes the width of the text - like the iris of an eye contracts and expands.

Comment: I'm able to replicate that behavior manually... I can try to play with it a little more tonight.

Comment: hmm I'm completely stumped. Like you, I would certainly expect this to be in the `Adjustments` collection, but I also see the `Adjustments.Count` is `0`. I tried creating this as WordArt instead of a text box, but same results.  Have you tried posting this on MSDN?

Comment: I haven't. But I'm looking thru their answered questions now to see if I find anything.

Comment: I notice that the Adjustments handle is typically yellow. I'm not sure what this pink handle is, but looking at the available properties/methods of the `TextEffect` or even the parent `Shape`, there does not seem to be any way to do this. Good luck, and if you find a solution, do post it here!